# Outlook 2010: re-enabling conversation deletion confirmation prompt

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I am using Outlook 2010 with "conversation view" turned on. When deleting a conversation, I used to get a pop-up confirmation dialog informing me that all messages in the conversation would be deleted, and prompting me to confirm that this was my intent. On this confirmation dialog there was a checkbox to hide the prompt in the future. I checked this box by mistake once. Is there any way to get that confirmation dialog box back?

Answer (score 0):

A coworker of mine solved it, hooray!

> You can restore it by deleting the values in the following registry
>   key using regedit.
>
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\MicrosoftOffice\14.0\Outlook\Options\General\PONT_STRING
>
> That particular dialog box is values 76 and 78. To restore all of the
>   "Do not show again" options in Outlook, clear out all of the values.